# Noisy sounds in the patterns of Fl Studio

Tags: sound, fl-studio

When I open Demo songs on Fl Studio (Demo Projects -> Demo songs)
on some patterns i hear noisy sounds, I tried so hard to fix it but I couldn't
.could someone please tell how can I fix it cause it's been driving me crazy :(

Comment: With nothing to go on but that limited description, I'd guess maybe some of the demo sounds were in a corrupted download. This issue would probably be better addressed to the makers of FL Studio.

Comment: Another possibility is that these particular demos are using a lot of CPU and your computer is suffering from 'buffer underruns' - short drop outs that occur when the computer can't generate the audio fast enough.

Comment: Is it running with demo plugins, don't they make interference after some time? It also might be your audio diver settings. Try using AISO.